# How to find and manipulate a users home folders in python?

Tags: python, linux, unix, localization, home-directory

Say I had a program that identified what commonly used home folders were in use in a users home directory, and then allowed the user to remove and create home directories as he pleased.

This could be done very simply if your target audient spoke only english, however unfortunately that's not the case. So my program would be innefective to a large audience of people.

My question here is how would you go about identifying the folders that were active (taken foreign languages into account) and then doing the above?

I'm aware of `xdg-user-dir` and `xdf-user-dirs-update` and how they can handle the localization, and create them in the users own language, but using them seems to be problematic. My `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file has many of the paths incomplete, and it's the same story for many other of my distributions in VM's, even though I have the folders and were created by `xdg`.

So, I can't figure out how to do this, without having a translation team translate the folders name and then checking the users locale and basing it that way. But surely there's a better way than this?

Comment: What does localisation have to do with this? Changing your language settings won't change the path to the `$HOME` dir for a given user.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm talking about the commonly used home folders like `Downloads`, `Documents`, etc. Not the home directory path.

Comment: Then your terminology is confusing. You are talking about common directory *inside* a home directory, whose names may have been localized. There is no standard for that, that I am aware of. Not for the names or purposes of these directories, nor for how to detect their presence.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Depending on the linux installer that was used, the large majority of the time the folder names are translated into the users selected language. Now, I may be mistaken but I'm pretty sure that the tool usually used for this is `xdg-user-dirs`. I just can't figure out how to do this. There are utilities that do it, although I'm not aware of how, and I would prefer to not have to dig through their source code.

Comment: Perhaps [pyxdg](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyxdg) can help here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I google around, and checked the source code for it, and there doesn't appear to be any compatability to find the commonly used folders in the home directory. Just grabbing locales, and other commonly used folders. I'll look around some more, there may be something similar, that has the compatibility I'm looking for.